# Running JFrog in MicroK8s open files too low

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I would like run a local Maven proxy with JFrog on my Microk8s instance. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Max number of open files 1024, is too low. Cannot run Artifactory!
```

My deployment yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jfrog
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jfrog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jfrog
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jfrog
        image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: Europe/Berlin
        - name: EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: -Dartifactory.maven.suppressPomConsistencyChecks=true
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8081
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 512Mi
```

The recommended setting for open files is `32000` and the minimum to get the services started is `10000`. The container image for JFrog is started as a non-root user. Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the output of `microk8s.kubectl exec <jfrog_pod_name> -- cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`?

Comment: For the reason the container crashes on startup, I've added a `command` directive in the deployment file like this:

`command:
    - /bin/cat
    - /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

On startup I get the output of `1000000` in the log output.

Comment: Where do you get the `ERROR: Max number of open files...` from? Can you share more details regarding your build and how your are running it?

Comment: Sure, I run the container image provided by JFrog. Fortunately the Dockerfile how they build the image is included and I've extracted it here: https://gist.github.com/indigo423/45b2c790c7bd38a3660b215984b0c882

I have also extracted the entry point script which runs a function called `checkULimits` which is the reason for the error message see here:

https://gist.github.com/indigo423/f7441e5c40fdc62d15e9499b71031147#file-entrypoint-artifactory-sh-L54

Comment: But where do you see the error message, in which logs?

Comment: Sorry, here is the procedure what I do to get this error message:

1. `microk8s.kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`
2. `microk8s.kubectl get pods` to get the frog pod name
3. `microk8s.kubectl logs <jfrog-pod-name>`

Comment: Here is the full output of the logs output: https://gist.github.com/indigo423/c30c6241b6a39230264e466a540d4f8b

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following line in */etc/sysconfig/docker*:

```
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"
```